# How to keep track of failed batches in spark streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I am using Spark Streaming with Kafka using the direct approach.Basically when there is multiple tasks failure after certain retries at the batch level the entire batch gets failed and the data gets lost.I want to know if there is any mechanism to track those failed batches with lost offset ranges so that I can reprocess those lost data again.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming offset commit is done at the check pointing. But there are few problems using check pointing. One being not able to process the message but commiting the offset. Plus your spark output system should be idempotent.

So its better to store offset externally in some distributed storage like HBase, zookeeper.
To do so offset have to be stored to the external storage, when the message has been processed by the spark. There are 2 ways.

1.Use commit commitAsync(offsetRanges) of kafka. This is done after the msg is processed by spark. In this case your system need to be idempotent as there can be case where you will end up processing the same msg twice. Think of case at the time of commiting offset, your application crashes.

eg. taken from spark doc.

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

  // some time later, after outputs have completed
  stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}
```

2. Use transaction to complete your offset. This make sure that your transaction which starts from saving spark process result, till, commit the offset is done in a transaction way.

eg. from spark doc.

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

      val results = yourCalculation(rdd)

      // begin your transaction

      // update results
      // update offsets where the end of existing offsets matches the beginning of this batch of offsets
      // assert that offsets were updated correctly

      // end your transaction
    }
```

You can always set the offset by reading from the storage and setting in createDirectStream parameter at the time of restart, as follows.

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Assign[String, String](fromOffsets.keys.toList, kafkaParams, fromOffsets)
)
```

Comment: Basically, my doubt is to reprocess those failed batches not offset management.Whenever you start spark-streaming it will automatically commit offset to either Kafka or external storage based on your implementation.But for long-running spark job, there might be some batches gets failed and the data would be lost but the job is running as usual.I want to reprocess those failed batch data

Comment: I guess you did not understand the point. You have to commit the offset for a partition only when the spark has process the batch successfully. That is what is shown in the second approach.

Comment: I am already following this approach in order to save offset for processed batches.But there are still a couple of batches which are failed and due to that failure, the offset for those batches are not saved successfully.How to recover those failed batch offset?

Comment: Here the problem is reprocessing the intermittent failures. If we recover from error scenario then the offset management will commit new offsets ignoring/forgetting about intermittent failures.